# How to view Failing Authentication Logs for a specific iOS Application

Tags: xcode, logs, authentication, apple-configurator

How do I view specific logs for a specific iOS Application?  It is not a native iOS Application.

It is an iOS Application installed from an MDM solution.  It is an iOS Application that allow the user to check his/her email.

I am not looking for Crash Logs but I am looking for Logs that will tell me why the User Authentication failed.  I am looking for some kind of authentication logs messages failures and see at least if it was a Token Authentication Issue, or Certificates Issue or something like that.

Reading some online articles, I can connect the iOS device to a Mac OS X device, and I can use Apple Configurator 2 or XCode to view the crash logs.  But again, I need the authentication user logs for a specific application not the crash logs.
Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not see the log file you need along the crash logs in XCode or Apple Configurator 2, then the log file is not available here.

In that case the log file is something proprietary to the app - i.e. for example just a text file that the app writes to during execution. In that case, the text file is within the app's document folder. You can use the "Files" app on the iOS device to look inside the app's folder for the log file.

If you do not see the log file there, I think you might be mistaken that there should be a log file at all. If you haven't got a manual, support web site or similar stating that there should be a log file, there usually isn't a log file.

You could use a program like iDevice Manager or similar to browse the file system on the iOS device to look for a log file within the app's folder. This is normally not something you want or need to do.